# How do I hide sidebar content (text) and show only icons inside Files app (Nautilus) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I want to hide the contents (text) in sidebar and only want to see the icons inside the Files app (Nautilus).

[image: Hide the content and show only icons in files app]

Comment: Maybe the issue is about Nautilus. And the poster doesn't want the text, only the icons. AFAICT, that's not possible. It's hide the sidebar totally or show it. In any case, OP should clarify. As it stands, the question is unclear.

Comment: If you are willing to hide only the text, but keep the icons, I don't think that's *easily* doable. Note that there aren't actually two columns (one for the icons and the other for the texts), it's [an illusion created by the theme](https://askubuntu.com/a/1152802/480481).