# Nautilus left panel modification

Tags: nautilus

How can I remove the huge folder name tab from Nautilus? Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable (or enable) the left sidebar *entirely* by pressing the <kbd>F9</kbd> key.

If you are willing to hide only the text, but keep the icons, I don't think that's easily doable. Note that there *aren't* actually two columns (i.e. one for the icons and the other for the texts). There is a single column and the illusion of two columns is created by the theme Ubuntu uses. With the GNOME-default Adwaita theme it would look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Yes you are correct i just want to hide text. So as i can read its not doable. But in some version i don't remember there was an option to do so.